# async await node.js skips the second await statement save mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async.js, ecmascript-2017

I am using await async in node.js ES6 ...

```
async insertIngot(body, callback) {

    console.log('*** ItemsRepository.insertIngot');

    console.log(body);

    const data = await this.getItemsTest();
    console.log('*** getItems ok');
    items = data.items;

    let item = new Ingot();

    item.ingotName = body.ingotName;
    item.formulaName = body.formulaName;
    item.items = items;

    await item.save();

    return item;
}
```

The first await works and then it skips the rest of code and throws an error :

(node:16612) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: FYI, async/await is not part of ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mongoose, you need to define the type of promise you would like to use. You are using built in es6 promises, so to tell mongoose that, you need to do this:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Here is the doc: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#plugging-in-your-own-promises-library

Comment: Idk why it skip the rest of the code so. It's just a warning. An idea?

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I don't know if we can be sure it is skipping, the posted code doesn't have any debugging in it, plus, the error is thrown at the `save()`, so we know it is trying to save. It probably isn't saving because of the message that is getting thrown.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Fair enough, interesting. Thanks :)

Comment: @Danish I think you might need to change `async insertIngot` to `async function insertIngot`